# PDF from another API corrupted after conversion and email via Sendgrid

Tags: python, base64, sendgrid

I was working with an API that sends a binary file of the the requested PDF. I wanted to email it as attachment via SendGrid, but I keep running into problems.

So far I have tried:

- Using it directly, no encoding what so ever. Result: corrupt file.
- Look in Sendgrid's doc. According to Sendgrid, the content should be "The Base64 encoded content of the attachment."
- Tried both base64.b64encode(attachment_data) & binascii.b2a_base64(attachment_data) . Result: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-13: ordinal not in range(128)
- Tried a type(attachment_data), which outputs " type 'unicode' ".
- Tried both base64.b64encode(attachment_data.encode("utf-8")) & binascii.b2a_base64(attachment_data.encode("utf-8")). Result: corrupt file stating "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC could not open 'property_info.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

I find some Q&A on both Stackoverflow and SendGrid's own Python Github, but it seems to mostly work with the pdf file, not binary data. Most just seems to say "encode it to utf-8", but in this case it just ends up corrupted. Any clues on what else I can do it send the file correctly?

Here are the function that does the Sendgrid:

```
def to_sendgrid(my_email, other_email, text, attachment_data):
    subject = "Sample pdf attached."
    from_email = Email(my_email)
    to_email = Email(other_email)
    content = Content("text/plain", text)
    mail = Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)
    attachment_data = base64.b64encode(attachment_data.encode("utf-8"))
    attachment = Attachment()
    attachment.set_content(attachment_data)
    attachment.set_type("application/pdf")
    attachment.set_filename("sample.pdf")
    attachment.set_disposition("attachment")
    attachment.set_content_id("Sample")
    mail.add_attachment(attachment)

    try:
        sendgrid_client.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail.get())
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

Comment: content-type should be `application/octet-stream;`  - Can you share just the part of the code you wrote if that doesn't work.  If that content-type doesn't work, `application/pdf` should help simpler email clients.  - accidentally submitted without that last sentence.  Possibly related to your ascii issue, are you using windows?  If so, perhaps this could help https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console

Comment: I previously used application/pdf. I just tried it with octet-stream, but still getting corrupted pdf. I am going to edit my post to show the code. I am using Mac.

Comment: how are you opening the file?  `open("path to file", "rb")` or just `open("path to file")`  also the .encode("utf-8") is likely corrupting the pdf data.  Similar effect to you taking html like `<a>Some anchor</a>` and converting it to `&lt;a&gt;Some\ anchor&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: Earlier I tried to use open(attachment_data, "rb"), and I just tried open(attachment_data) now. In both case, I got the error "TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not unicode".

Comment: A lot more seems to be going wrong here then just an issue with SendGrid's API. open is an alias to file and argument one is a string of the path to the source pdf file. if attachment_data is the contents of the pdf, it's not going to work  - https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open    I would recommend you try asking http://reddit.com/r/learnpython for help.